# Error in Python app, how can I read the log file

Tags: python, flask

I'm a Rails developer and I'm trying to install an opensource app called [Liveblog](https://github.com/liveblog/liveblog)

Everything is ok with desktop, but they provide also a mobile app for iOS and Android and I cannot use it for an error.

I log the post request using nginx and this is the log.

```
{\"username\":\"xxxxx\",\"password\":\"xxxxx\"}
37.117.49.57 - - [24/Dec/2018:16:59:20 +0100] "POST /api/auth HTTP/1.1" 500 157 "-" "Live Blog Reporter/org.sourcefabric.LiveBlogReporter (22; OS Version 12.1.2 (Build 16C101))" "-"
```

The hash params with user and pass looks good.

In the application log I have this error:

```
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 | ERROR:eve:Exception on /api/auth [POST]
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 | Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     raise value
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/endpoints.py", line 56, in collections_endpoint
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     response = post(resource)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/methods/common.py", line 284, in rate_limited
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return f(*args, **kwargs)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/auth.py", line 79, in decorated
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return f(*args, **kwargs)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/methods/common.py", line 1040, in decorated
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     r = f(resource, **combined_args)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/methods/post.py", line 40, in post
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return post_internal(resource, payl, skip_validation=False)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/methods/post.py", line 245, in post_internal
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     getattr(app, "on_insert_%s" % resource)(documents)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/events/events.py", line 77, in __call__
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     f(*a, **kw)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/src/superdesk-core/apps/auth/service.py", line 34, in on_create
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     user = self.authenticate(doc)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/src/superdesk-core/apps/auth/service.py", line 30, in authenticate
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     raise NotImplementedError()
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 | NotImplementedError
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 | ERROR:superdesk.errors:HTTP Exception 500 has been raised:
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 | [2018-12-24 16:59:20 +0100] [20670] [ERROR] Error handling request /api/auth
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 | Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     raise value
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/endpoints.py", line 56, in collections_endpoint
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     response = post(resource)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/methods/common.py", line 284, in rate_limited
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return f(*args, **kwargs)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/auth.py", line 79, in decorated
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return f(*args, **kwargs)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/methods/common.py", line 1040, in decorated
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     r = f(resource, **combined_args)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/methods/post.py", line 40, in post
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return post_internal(resource, payl, skip_validation=False)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/methods/post.py", line 245, in post_internal
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     getattr(app, "on_insert_%s" % resource)(documents)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/events/events.py", line 77, in __call__
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     f(*a, **kw)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/src/superdesk-core/apps/auth/service.py", line 34, in on_create
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     user = self.authenticate(doc)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/src/superdesk-core/apps/auth/service.py", line 30, in authenticate
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     raise NotImplementedError()
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 | NotImplementedError
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 | Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 176, in handle_request
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/flaskapp.py", line 1033, in __call__
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return super(Eve, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1410, in handle_exception
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return handler(e)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/src/superdesk-core/superdesk/factory/app.py", line 136, in server_error_handler
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return client_error_handler(return_error)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/src/superdesk-core/superdesk/factory/app.py", line 126, in client_error_handler
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return send_response(None, (error.to_dict(), None, None, error.status_code))
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/render.py", line 57, in decorated
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     r = f(*args, **kwargs)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/render.py", line 96, in send_response
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return _prepare_response(resource, *response if response else [None])
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/render.py", line 150, in _prepare_response
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     rendered = globals()[renderer](dct)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/render.py", line 303, in render_json
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     sort_keys=config.JSON_SORT_KEYS)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 399, in dumps
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     **kw).encode(obj)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 296, in encode
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 378, in iterencode
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return _iterencode(o, 0)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/io/mongo/mongo.py", line 57, in default
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return super(MongoJSONEncoder, self).default(obj)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eve/io/base.py", line 36, in default
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |   File "/opt/liveblog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 273, in default
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 |     o.__class__.__name__)
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 | TypeError: Object of type NotImplementedError is not JSON serializable
Dec 24 16:59:20 liveblog sh[20638]: 16:59:20 rest.1 | POST None status=500 time=0s size=0b
```

In a Rails log error I can understand where is the problem, here I cannot understand how routes in python works, so i cannot debug the issue. Is there any hint in the log that I can use to start debugging?

Answer (score 0):

It's explained with `Traceback (most recent call last):` => you can look at the last line of the traceback to check which line of code raised (thrown) the exception.

That's the line where to add a debugger breakpoint if the runtime values were not logged in the exception itself.

In your case: `raise NotImplementedError()` is a manual exception thrown in `/src/superdesk-core/apps/auth/service.py", line 30`.

Comment: I understand this but the method in service.py at line 30 is not so helpful... :-/

https://github.com/superdesk/superdesk-core/blob/master/apps/auth/service.py

I'm asking because I think maybe is a sort of json error... and the auth error is just a problem of json.

Comment: no idea why some configuration somewhere in the very big repository points to a non-implemented method ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ it's not Python's fault when using intermediate libraries to configure dispatch of dynamic calls - though in `flask` itself it is possible to configure 1:1 mapping between routes and methods (see the example in http://flask.pocoo.org/ => useless stack trace is due to the implementation details of the project)